# Facing issues on input submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing the issue that when I successfully submit my value then I set the value to empty, but it remains the same, console says it is empty but it's not in components.

I think it's a rendering issue because I am using separate component for input, I am using `useState` hook.

Input component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Input = (props) => {
  const [inn, setinn] = useState("")

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full p-5 justify-center items-center mx-auto gap-4 ">
      {props.title
        ? (
          <label for="helper-text" class={`block mb-1  w-[10%] text-xl text-gray-900 dark:text-white gap-5 ${props.classes}`}>
            {props.title}
          </label>
        ) : ("")
      }

      <input
        onChange={props.fn}
        type={props.type}
        id="helper-text"
        chk={props.chk} 
        aria-describedby="helper-text-explanation"
        class={`bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 w-[50%] text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 ${props.classes}`}
        placeholder={`Enter Your Valid ${props.name}`}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Input;
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Button from '../../components/Button'
import Input from '../../components/Input'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'

const AddTask = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({ content: "" })

  const dataSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data)

    try {
      if (data.content.trim() === "") {
        toast.error("Please Enter a Valid Task")
      } else { 
        const res = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/add-todo",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            credentials: "include"
          }
        )
        const response = await res.json()
        console.log(response)
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
          toast.success("Task Added Successfully")
          //   setInputs({content:e.target.value})
          setInputs({ content: "" })
        } else {
          toast.error(`Something Went Wrong : ${response.message}`)
        }
        setInputs({ ...inputs, content: "" })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error : ",error)
      toast.error(`Something Went Wrong: ${error}`)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => { 
    if (inputs.content.trim() === "") {
      setInputs({content:""})
    }
  } , [inputs.content])

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="w-[60%] mt-20  mx-auto flex justify-center item center flex-col">
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-3xl text-center font-bold mb-5">Add Task</h1>
        </div>

        <Input
          classes='w-full h-12 m-[0px]'
          name="click here to write task"
          type="text"
          chk={inputs}
          fn={(e) => {
            setInputs({ content: e.target.value })
          }}
        />
    
        <Button
          fn={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            dataSubmit(inputs)
          }}
          title="Add Task"
          classes="hover:bg-green-400 bg-zinc-600 flex text-center justify-center mt-5 mx-auto h-12 w-24"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddTask
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH67Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

in your Input component you need to catch updated input value using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {setInn(props.chk)}, [props.chk]);
```

and pass inn to input value instead of props.chk

Answer (score 0):

You have a "semi-controlled" form input, in that it has the `onChange` handler, but the issue is that there is nothing setting the input's value, e.g. it really isn't controlled at all.

Generally speaking, in React we typically use ***fully*** [controlled](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) form inputs, or we use ***fully*** [uncontrolled](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) form inputs.

- Controlled: Uses React state to hold the "source of truth", and passes `value` and `onChange` props to an input. The *state* is referenced when working with form data
- Uncontrolled: No state, add passes a `defaultValue` (*or `defaultChecked`*) prop and uses the form's `onSubmit` event object to access the form fields' values.

It is because the `Input` component isn't ***fully*** controlled that the `input` element still shows what was entered by the user.

It is also a bit of a React anti-pattern to duplicate passed props into local state, the `Input` component's `inn` state is unnecessary and should be removed.

```js
const Input = ({ classes, name, onChange, title, type, value }) => {
  return (
    <div className="fle ... ap-4 ">
      {!!title && (
        <label
          for="helper-text"
          class={`blo... ${classes}`}
        >
          {title}
        </label>
      )}    

      <input
        aria-describedby="helper-text-explanation"
        class={`bg-gr...  ${classes}`}
        id="helper-text"
        placeholder={`Enter Your Valid ${name}`}
        type={type}
        onChange={onChange} // <-- onChange handler
        value={value}       // <-- current input value
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

AddTask: Update the `Input` component rendering to pass the appropriate props.

```
<Input
  classes='w-full h-12 m-[0px]'
  name="click here to write task"
  type="text"
  value={inputs.content}      // <-- pass current input value
  onChange={(e) => {          // <-- pass change handler
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,              // <-- shallow copy existing state
      content: e.target.value // <-- set the content state value
    }));
  }}
/>
```